# Docker Socket.IO only works with docker run -it flags

Tags: node.js, socket.io, docker

I am trying to dockerize Socket.IO with the following commend. It works, the client side can archive a handshake and connect to the socket server.

```
//this works perfectly
docker run -it socket_io "node" "app"
```

However, what I want is to run my socket server with the following commend. But somehow, when I use this commend to run the socket server, the client side stuck at socket polling / connecting phase.

```
//this does not work, client stuck in socket polling
docker run socket_io "node" "app"
```

Any idea why this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: if it works with `-it` it means you need either a tty (for t) or an interactive mode (for i) or both

Answer (score 0):

You should try `docker run -d` mode, which will run your container in detached mode, leaving the container running in the background.

Also you can check this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/).